# use of angular js in web site

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello everyone,
               I am new to angular js. I want to know that for what reason we use the angular js instead of jquery. Please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Please just use jQuery.  If it makes you finish the new project faster then remember you get paid faster.  No one can reply fast enough to help you, so do what comes naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Angular JS 1.x has jqLite incorporated for basic interoperability but it's very common to use jQuery alongside Angular JS in production environments, mostly because many quality 3rd-party Angular modules depend on jQuery.

The basic benefits that really set Angular apart is 1. {{dataBinding}} in-line HTML 2. creating custom reuse-able  3. (dependency, injection) and 4. [modularization]

Further core benefits include refined templates for filters, loops, decorators, you'll really want to read the Angular docs a few times and play the tutorials from [thinkster.io](http://thinkster.io)

Then when you're comfortable with the framework, explore many repositories of Angular modules to extend capabilities further than jQuery allows, with less code to boot.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly used in single web page application. 
It helps you to load in light weight,
It simplifies the searching filtering and shorting in table.
It is very help full in decorating the web site.
In angular each tool was designed to affect the another tool you want, without using any other scripts.

pleas refer the below site for angularjs tutorial

https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/mean-stack-tutorial/